# How to store position of element into different container In sortablejs?

Tags: javascript, sortablejs

I have two containers left and right, I want to store the position of elements when dragged from left to right container or vise Versa.

When I rearrange the position of elements in the left container, it stores the position of element when the page is reloaded.

```
Sortable.create(document.getElementById("left"), {
group: {
name: "shared"
// pull: "clone", // To clone: set pull to 'clone'
// put: true // Do not allow items to be put into this list
},
// sort: false, // To disable sorting: set sort to false
animation: 350,
dataIdAttr: "data-id",
// draggable: ".item",
store: {
/**
* Get the order of elements. Called once during initialization.
* @param {Sortable} sortable
* @returns {Array}
*/
get: function(sortable) {
var order = localStorage.getItem(sortable.options.group.name);

console.log("Left Get = " + order);
return order ? order.split("|") : [];
},

/**
* Save the order of elements. Called onEnd (when the item is dropped).
* @param {Sortable} sortable
*/
set: function(sortable) {
var order = sortable.toArray();
console.log("Left set = " + order);
localStorage.setItem(sortable.options.group.name, order.join("|"));
}
},
onEnd: function(/**Event*/ evt) {
console.log(evt.item.dataset.id, "datasetID"); // element's new index within parent
// var order = sortable.toArray();
// $(".visuaplayoutCol02").attr(
// "value",
// $(".visuaplayoutCol01").attr("value") + "," + evt.item.dataset.id
// );
}
});

// sort: false
Sortable.create(document.getElementById("right"), {
group: {
name: "shared"
// pull: "clone" // To clone: set pull to 'clone'
},
animation: 350,
dataIdAttr: "data-id",
// draggable: ".item",

store: {
/**
* Get the order of elements. Called once during initialization.
* @param {Sortable} sortable
* @returns {Array}
*/
get: function(sortable) {
var order = localStorage.getItem(sortable.options.group.name);
console.log("right get = " + order);
return order ? order.split("|") : [];
},

/**
* Save the order of elements. Called onEnd (when the item is dropped).
* @param {Sortable} sortable
*/
set: function(sortable) {
var order = sortable.toArray();
console.log("right set = " + order);

localStorage.setItem(sortable.options.group.name, order.join("|"));
}
},
onEnd: function(/**Event*/ evt) {
console.log(evt.item.dataset.id, "datasetID"); // element's new index within parent
// var order = sortable.toArray();
// $(".visuaplayoutCol02").attr(
// "value",
// $(".visuaplayoutCol01").attr("value") + "," + evt.item.dataset.id
// );
},
onAdd: function(/**Event*/ evt) {
console.log(evt.item.dataset.id, " onAdd datasetID");
}
});
```

when we drag the element from left to right container or right to left container or within the container. it should store the position when the page is reloaded

Comment: It should be saving already... What version of Sortable are you using?

Comment: yes its saving into same container but want to save into different container.
can you help me?

Comment: "sortablejs": "^1.6.1",

Comment: The version you are using is broken, upgrade to the latest version and it should work. 1.9.0 should also work if you don't want to use an RC version.

Comment: Hi Owen,
It is not working also after upgrade the version.

Comment: please make a JSBin so I can investigate